# Tomcat + OpenJPA

Tags: tomcat, openjpa

I am trying to migrate an application from WLP to Tomcat, when trying to deploy the war , I am getting the below exception

**org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent:**

I tried adding javaagent to enable runtime loading
JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:"$CATALINA_HOME/lib/openjpa-2.X.jar

as mentioned in [here](https://www.vodori.com/setting-up-openjpa-2-with-spring-junit-maven-3-and-tomcat/) but no success.

Any suggestion or points.

Comment: Trying to add :- <target name="enhance">
  <!-- define the openjpac task; this can be done at the top of the    -->
  <!-- build.xml file, so it will be available for all targets      -->
  <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask"/>

  <!-- invoke enhancer on all .java files below the model directory -->
  <openjpac>
    <fileset dir=".">
      <include name="**/beans/*.java" />
    </fileset>
  </openjpac>
</target>

Comment: As mentioned here [link] (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html)

Comment: Are you sure you need "runtime optimization" aka weaving. The feature is required for J2EE containers, in a J2SE environment you need a JavaAgent. Typically weaving is used to emit byte-code to extend classes which are used in a ManyToOne/OneToOne, so these can be Lazily fetched. Unless you you disable the shared cache, or have a lot of data such optimizations may not be needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest using a compile-time optimization. It's a task where JPA implementation auto-generates JPA functions for jpa enhanced class files.

See this build.xml in [ScopedEntityManager utility project in Github](https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager/blob/master/example_webapp/build.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="jpaexample" default="build" basedir=".">
   ...clip...
    <target name="compile" depends="clean" description="Compile classes">
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" target="1.7" source="1.7" encoding="ISO-8859-1" 
            debug="true" debuglevel="lines,source" includeantruntime="false"
            excludes="" >
            <classpath refid="libs" />
        </javac>
        <antcall target="jpaenhance" />
    </target>


    <target name="jpaenhance" description="Preprocess entity classes, enhance for JPA use">
        <path id="jpa.enhancement.classpath">
            <pathelement location="${classes}" />
            <fileset dir="./webapp/WEB-INF/lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
                <exclude name="${name}.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </path>

        <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask">
            <classpath refid="jpa.enhancement.classpath" />
        </taskdef>  
        <openjpac>
            <classpath refid="jpa.enhancement.classpath" />
            <config propertiesFile="./webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml" />           
        </openjpac>
    </target>
   ...clip...
</project>
```